# Question on Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ open, and $W \subset \operatorname{Grass}_d(\mathbb{P}^n)$ be the set of linear subspaces which are contained in $V$. Then the question is whether $W$ is open in $\operatorname{Grass}_d(\mathbb{P}^n)$?

Comment: Do you mean "...which are contained in $V$"?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much.

Comment: Do you know Plucker coordinates?